# filter DateAndTime list to time is gone or upcoming two part

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one List:

```
List<String> dateTimeList = [
    "20-Feb-2023 at 10:30AM-Sun",
    "20-Feb-2023 at 07:30PM-Sun",
    "20-Feb-2023 at 07:30AM-Sun",
    "20-Feb-2023 at 06:30PM-Sun"
  ];
```

and i want to filter this list in this type:

```
List<String> timeHasGone = [
   "20-Feb-2023 at 07:30AM-Sun",
   "20-Feb-2023 at 10:30AM-Sun"
];

List<String> timeHasNotGone = [
"20-Feb-2023 at 07:30PM-Sun",
"20-Feb-2023 at 06:30PM-Sun"
];
```

how to filter in this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your own formater for your date format or use formattedString with [DateTime.parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html).

Then use [List.where](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/where.html) то filter your lists using `DateTime.isBefore` or `DateTime.isAfter`;

The code below works only if dates is formattedString. Otherwise you need to implement `yourParserOrDateTimeParse`.

```
List<String> dateTimeList = [
    "20-Feb-2023 at 10:30AM-Sun",
    "20-Feb-2023 at 07:30PM-Sun",
    "20-Feb-2023 at 07:30AM-Sun",
    "20-Feb-2023 at 06:30PM-Sun"
  ];

  final timeHasGone = dateTimeList
      .where((element) =>
          yourParserOrDateTimeParse(element).isBefore(DateTime.now()))
      .toList();
  final timeHasNotGone = dateTimeList
      .where((element) =>
          yourParserOrDateTimeParse(element).isAfter(DateTime.now()))
      .toList();

DateTime yourParserOrDateTimeParse(String element) => DateTime.parse(element);
```